# CORS - Ajax or XMLHttpRequest type GET with "Authorization" get error 307

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors, authorization

I need to do a CORS request type GET with "Authorization" in header but for some reason it didn't work... I got 307 Internal Redirect with error "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" or i got 401 Unauthorized if using HTTPS.

I tried this :

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://exemple.com/api/ajax.php",
     type: "GET",
       withCredentials: true, 
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer A5MjE2DA1LCJzaWduIjoiZGJYTExNjM==');},
       success: function() { 
       alert('Success!' + xhr.responseText);}
  });
```

And this :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://exemple.com/api/ajax.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer A5MjE2DA1LCJzaWduIjoiZGJYTExNjM==");
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

Got error 307 Internal Redirect with error "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

Then server side it's looks ok with `("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` so what is wrong? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is failing CORS preflight check. With 307 redirect, the server is not responding to the preflight OPTIONS request and redirecting instead.

You need to configure the server to implement CORS properly. There are many libraries out there that do that. But you can do it manually if you know how.

The server needs to respond to the OPTIONS verb and reply with CORS headers. In a preflight the allow-origin must be absolute and a wild card is not allowed. For allow-methods return GET. For allow-headers return Authorization. If you are using credentials (cookies) set Allow-Credentials to True.

Your preflight headers should look like this:

```
Cross-Origin-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Cross-Origin-Allow-Methods: GET
Cross-Origin-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Cross-Origin-Allow-Credentials: True
```

Comment: Something look wrong in my request headers, this `Accept:*/*` i need to send `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin-Allow-Credentials: True
prevent
Cross-Origin-Allow-Origin: *

You must provide the exact origin

Answer (score -1):

My headers is like this:

```
Cross-Origin-Allow-Origin: *
Cross-Origin-Allow-Methods: GET
Cross-Origin-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Cross-Origin-Allow-Credentials: True
```

My headers looks already right... so what is wrong ?